# Retry limit reached

Tags: mailgun

Haven't received emails on a dev server for a couple days -

Retry limit reached. Dropped: alerts@ → "": 498 No MX for .

The MX records are set properly for the domain which is active on mailgun. Does anyone know what's going on.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. [sf] would be better for questions like this.

Comment: Even tho this is configuration related. => Have you set up another MX record as well? You can receive only mails to one mail-server. It's not possible to receive mails with two mx records.